# Angular2: provide current route to parent component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing, angular2-components

To start with: The application I build at the moment is an Angular2(RC3) one (with the @angular/routerv3.0.0-alpha.8 module).

This app consists of a parent component including different header components which should be selected according to the current route. In short:

```
route: localhost:4200/login => display login header component,
route: localhost:4200/home => display home header component etc.
```

In the parent components template there is a switch which looks like:

```
<span [ngSwitch]="dataStore.currentRoute">
    <span *ngSwitchCase="'/login'"><login-header></login-header></span>
    <span *ngSwitchCase="'/home'"><home-header></home-header></span>
</span>
<div class="content"><router-outlet></router-outlet></div>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

Where **dataStore** in the parent component is defined as:

```
private dataStore: {
    currentRoute: string
};
```

All my efforts so far didn't result in a working solution. I tried to create a routeStore which provides a custom Observable and looks like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class RouteStore {
    private dataStore: {
        currentRoute: string
    };
    private _currentRoute$: BehaviorSubject<string>;

    constructor(private routeHelper: RouteHelperService) {
        this.dataStore = {currentRoute: this.routeHelper.getCurrentBaseRoute()};
        this._currentRoute$ = <BehaviorSubject<string>>new BehaviorSubject(this.dataStore.currentRoute);
    }

    get currentRoute$() {
        return this._currentRoute$.asObservable();
    }

    public updateCurrentRoute() {
        this.dataStore = {currentRoute: this.routeHelper.getCurrentBaseRoute()};
        this._currentRoute$.next(this.dataStore.currentRoute);
    }
}
```

This part is able to provide data to the parent when I navigate to another route via a button click like:

```
userIconClick(userName: string) {
    this.router.navigate(['/home', userName]).then(() => this.routeStore.updateCurrentRoute());
  }
```

But as soon as I refresh the page or initialize the app it throws the

```
Expression has changed after it was checked.
```

error.

Also my effort to handle all routing changes inside the parent component only by using the router like

```
this.route.url.subscribe(urlPathArray => this.dataStore.currentRoute = '/' + urlPathArray[0].path);
```

didn't result in an acceptable result, as the path property of the **urlPathArray** is always returning an empty string (meaning the route of the parent component).

How can I get the currently active route to be passed to the parent components **dataStore** objects **currentRoute** property to rerun the ngSwitch statement and display the correct header?

Comment: Can you provide exact error.  property on which these error is coming.     Please try router.events for subscription and check for navigationEnd object router.events.subscribe((e) => { e instance of NavigationEnd ? ///your logic : do nothing})

Comment: @ArpitAgarwal the error is throwns in the parent components template (which includes the ngSwitch statement) and says: `Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: ''. Current value: '/'`

What do I need to include into my parent component to use NavigationEnd in the instanceof as I get `Cannot find name 'NavigationEnd'` thrown when I try to use it. Thanks for your effort so far

Comment: forget about the NavigationEnd part, I had a typo in the import ;)

Comment: @ArpitAgarwal your solution worked like a charm, craete an answer out of it and I will mark it as the right one :) thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be handled using router [events](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Router-interface.html#!#events-anchor). 
Add a subscription to events check for [NavigationEnd](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/NavigationEnd-class.html) object  and move your logic there

```
router.events.subscribe(e => { 
    if (e instance of NavigationEnd) 
    {
        ///your logic 
    }
});
```